# react and redux: Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Going through udemy tutorial and got stuck and for some reason can't figure out what happaned. I went through all my code and it looks right as far as I can tell compared to the tutorial. Code:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

searchbar.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {fetchWeather} from '../actions/index';
export default class SearchBar extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {term: ''}
        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this)
    }
    onInputChange(e){
        console.log(e.target.value)
        this.setState({
            term: e.target.value
        })
    }
    onFormSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
    }
    render(){

        return (

            <form onSubmit ={this.onFormSubmit} className = "input-group">
                < input
                placeholder =" Get a forecast"
                className = "form-control"
                value = {this.state.term}
                onChange = {this.onInputChange}
                />
                <span className = "input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" className = "btn btn-secondary">Submit </button>
                </span>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({fetchWeather}, dispatch);
}
export default connect (null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

reducers/index.js

```
    import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = 'c4c2ff174cb65bad330f7367cc2a36fa'
const ROOT_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=appid=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city){
    let url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
    let request = axios.get(url);

    return {
        type: FETCH_WEATHER,
        payload: request
    };

}
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SearchBar from '../containers/search_bar';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you missing code in your reducers/index file? There's no reducer there and you're not exporting a default so `reducers` will be undefined in your main index file....

Comment: Function `fetchWeather` in `reducers/index.js` looks more like an action, not a reducer. Are you sure you do not mistake in the provided code?

Comment: @azium that is the code that was in the tutorial, i have to just go off the video and it matches as far as i can tell, this is the tutorial: https://www.udemy.com/react-redux/learn/v4/t/lecture/4284600

Comment: Well it looks like you don't know what a reducer is. I would read this: http://redux.js.org/index.html

Comment: @azium well this is exactly whats in the code so it's not me its the teacher if you claim that is the issue yet his code works fine. Also maybe that is just the index file in reducers folder, not the actual reducer itself, ya?

Comment: Not sure what else you're expecting from us here on stackoverflow. I stand by my suggestion, read the official readme / docs and you will have a clearer understanding of how to move forward.

Comment: Your code got a little mixed up, what you have in `reducers/index.js` is your action & needs to be in `actions/index.js`. You are even importing it as such in your searchbar component: `import {fetchWeather} from '../actions/index';`. Your reducer will be a switch statement that makes use of `FETCH_WEATHER` and is definitely covered correctly in that course (I took it myself a few months back when I was first introduced to Redux).

Also as azium mentioned, the docs for Redux are outstanding, be sure to check them out.

Comment: thanks you helped e figure it out, create an answer and accept my appreciation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer,

Your code got a little mixed up, the block that you have in `reducers/index.js` is your action and should be located in `actions/index.js` instead. As mentioned you are importing it from there in your `searchbar` component:

`import {fetchWeather} from '../actions/index';`

The reducer here should be making use of the `FETCH_WEATHER` type that you are setting up in your action in order to update the state of the redux store, so something along the lines of:

```
switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
        return [action.payload.data].concat(state);
}

return state;
```

Then either export that directly or make use of `combineReducers` from redux to return a single reducer function if you have more than one.

Link to the always awesome: [DOCS](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html)